# Can Mail count unread messages (for the Dock icon) from only some of my accounts?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have 7 mail accounts configured with Apple Mail. The dock icon shows the count of new emails for all of my accounts. How can I disable notification for 2 of those 7 accounts, so it just shows me the counter for the other 5 accounts?

Answer (score 6):

Do a SmartMailbox with the folders from which you want the counts to come, and then select that in Mail's General settings --> "Dock unread count" (it's the fourth drop down list)

Comment: Still works great, 12 years later...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this natively, but [DockStar](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/dockstar/index.html) offers this kind of functionality, among other things. Their FAQ states that the latest version supports Lion, as well.